# Unittest a function which runs another function twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a unittest for a piece of code, which runs a function twice.

```py
## in [module.py]
def check_my_documents(t: str, v: str, r: str):
  is_texture_data = os.path.isdir(t)    
  is_zip_data = os.path.isfile(v)    
  is_csv_data = os.path.isfile(r)
  return (is_texture_data, is_zip_data, is_csv_data)

@patch('module.os.path.isfile')
@patch('module.os.path.isdir')
def test_check_my_documents(mocked_file, mocked_dir):
  expected_result = (True, True, False)
  mocked_file.side_effect = [True, False]
  mocked_dir.side_effect = [True]
  assert check_print_files(t, v, r) === expected_result
```

I thought this would work, but it returns `/Users/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1154: StopIteration`

Edit: I am using Pytest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not fully understood how to write unittest tests...

The `unittest` module is intended to allow you to use classes derived from `unittest.TestCase`. You'd better stick to that...

When you use more that one `@patch` decorator, the mocks are added as new parameters in reverse order, because the last `@patch` is the innest one and because of that will provide the first parameter.

Once this is observed, you should end with a code close to:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import module

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('os.path.isfile')
    @patch('os.path.isdir')
    def test_check_my_documents(self, mocked_dir, mocked_file):
        expected_result = (True, True, False)
        mocked_file.side_effect = [True, False]
        mocked_dir.side_effect = [True]
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, check_print_files('t', 'v', 'r'))

unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I forgot to mention that I am using pytest instead unittest. Do the same remarks apply in this case?